# Laravel Using Schedule to create entries every week for multiple users

Tags: laravel, cron, schedule

I am trying to auto generate multiple entries, one for each user every Monday morning at 07:00.

Also it needs to check that an entry doesn't exist as the users can create there own if needed, I already validate manual creation with Requests timesheetRequest.php

Console/Commands/AddSheets.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Models\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use DB;

class AddSheets extends Command
{
protected $signature = 'add:sheets';

protected $description = 'Generate new timesheet for all active users';

public function handle()
{
    /**
     * get users where active
     * if does not exist, create a new timesheet for each user for current week 2018-11 W/C 24-03 MS
     */
    $users = User::with('profile')->where('status_id', '1')->get();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $currentweek = Carbon::now()
            ->year . '-' . Carbon::now('w')
            ->weekOfYear . ' W/C ' . Carbon::now()
            ->day . '-' . Carbon::now()
            ->month . ' ' . $user->profile->code();
        DB::table('timesheets')->insert([
            'name' => $currentweek,
            'status_id' => 1,
            'user_id' => $user->id
        ]);
    }
    $this->info('Add:Sheets Command Run successfully!');
}
}
```

with

Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use App\Models\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use DB;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{

protected $commands = [
    Commands\AddSheets::class
];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('add:sheets')->weekly()->mondays('07:00');
}

protected function commands()
{
    require base_path('routes/console.php');
}
}
```

When I run

```
php artisan add:sheets
```

I get

```
In Builder.php line 2445:

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::code()
```

But I am unsure what this means and can't see anything in the source code to suggest anything other than line 2445 is the error message for an exception.

I am now at a loss.

please help

Comment: Try `$user->profile->code` instead of `$user->profile->code()`

Comment: Your `$currentweek` variable is all over the place, what are you trying to achieve with that variable?

Comment: @RamyHerrira top spotter, that was the issue entirely, thanks so much, you are a life saver :)

Comment: @Asur the output is to create this 2018-11 W/C 24-03 MS, made up of YEAR-WEEK W/C DAY-MONTH USERCODE, if there is a prettier way to do this I would love to tidy it up a bit, thanks

Comment: @Starks I've posted a solution, check it out and let me know if it solves the problem (and IMO is much cleaner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update this variable declaration:

```
$currentweek = Carbon::now()
    ->year . '-' . Carbon::now('w')
    ->weekOfYear . ' W/C ' . Carbon::now()
    ->day . '-' . Carbon::now()
    ->month . ' ' . $user->profile->code(); // Here
```

to

```
$currentweek = Carbon::now()->format("y-W \W/C d-m") . ' ' . $user->profile->code();
```

The error you are getting is because you are trying to use the `code()` method of the `profile` model and it doesn't exist, make sure you have said method on the correct object, if you are trying to access a property use `$user->profile->code` instead like this:

```
$currentweek = Carbon::now()->format("y-W \W/C d-m") . ' ' . $user->profile->code;
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks @Asur, I modified it slightly to $currentweek = Carbon::now()->format("Y-W \W/C d-m") . ' ' . $user->profile->code; so I could get the full year 2018, but it works a treat :)

Comment: @Starks Glad it helped you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the @Asur that your Carbon::now() statement in `$current_week` looks pretty wild.  In a case like this if the error message is not informative what I do is add targeted `echo`, `var_dump()` and `dd()` statements at successive points in the code which enables you to pinpoint where the error is happening. e.g. as the first line in the foreach loop you should insert `echo 'now in foreach loop';` then certainly do a `dd($current_week)` after the next line and take a look at what that's giving you.

Just noticed @Rami is also totally right - to access a property you don't use `()`, that syntax is to access either a method or a query builder object. The error looks like the attempt to access a query builder object which doesn't exist because `code` is a property.

Comment: The $currentweek is the name of the timesheet i.e. 2018-11 W/C 24-03 MS and doesn't cause the issue as @RamyHerrira was correct in pointing out. But yes you are correct the $currentweek variable is messy.  Also I need to check if the name is unique